# If x amount of a chemical starts to become harmful for a mice, then will 3000x amount of it start to get harmful for a human (3000 times heavier)?

Tags: human-biology, toxicology, mouse

My reasoning is simply that since human beings are 3000 times heavier than mice, the safety threshold for exposure to a chemical should be approximately 3000 times higher for human beings as compared to mice, assuming similar biology for both the organism.

Is there reason to believe this to be true? Or is this too naïve an assumption? If so, why?

As a concrete example, I am trying to understand what a [study](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fimmu.2019.03054/full) involving the harmful effect of 100 micrograms of TLR 7 agonist exposure to mice, can qualitatively say about its effect on a human being. Can we roughly assume that 300 milligram of the same TLR 7 agonist will have similar effect on human being?

**Edit:** Some people have shown concern that this question of mine is duplicate of another question that I asked - [How much of TLR 7 agonist is safe for human beings, as it is both linked to development of autoimmune diseases but is also used as Vaccine adjuvant?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/105590/how-much-of-tlr-7-agonist-is-safe-for-human-beings-as-it-is-both-linked-to-deve)

I think this is not the case. The earlier question is about a puzzle- TLR7 agonist is both helpful as an adjuvant and also triggers autoimmune disease in the *same* organism when the organism is exposed to different amount of the agonist. The question is, *what amount* of TLR7 exposure in *human beings* is hence safe?

On the other hand, this question is about how the toxic effect of any toxin *scales* with the body size of the victim? An answer to this question can *partially* answer the earlier question *if* there are murine models that have studied safe exposure levels to TLR7 on mice. But a proper answer to my previous question will involve how TLR7 agonist acts on human body, and why it is helpful at some concentration and why it backfires at some other concentration. The question, on the scaling of effect of a toxin, on the other hand, asks for a general scaling law.

Comment: This is seems to be a duplicate of your previous question [How much of TLR 7 agonist is safe for human beings, as it is both linked to development of autoimmune diseases but is also used as Vaccine adjuvant?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/105590/how-much-of-tlr-7-agonist-is-safe-for-human-beings-as-it-is-both-linked-to-deve).  Posting multiple similar questions comes across as spamming the site and is not going to be well received. Please delete this post and focus on improving the previous version.

Comment: There is a scaling factor, which used to be (body_weight)^0.67 (see [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1539-6924.1988.tb01158.x)), but I have no idea what the currently accepted value is, or even if body_weight (rather than, say, surface area) is the currently accepted criterion.

Comment: @tyersome I think the two questions are totally different. The TLR 7 question is about a puzzle- TLR7 has been shown both as harmful and useful at different concentration. The question is- when does this phase transition happen? The question in this post, on the other hand, is about how the effect of a toxin scale with the size of the victim? The first question is about transition point from helpful to harmful in the same organism. The second is about effect of the same amount of chemical in organisms of different size. Totally different questions. Just inspired from the same thing- TLR7.

Comment: I think you need to learn some terms - look up things like LD50, MIC (minimum inhibitory concentration) to start with. Compare those between different species.

Comment: It need not necessarily scale with body weight. Body weight (volume) does have an effect on the pharmacokinetics but drug/xenobiotic/toxin metabolism can also differ between different species.

Comment: This isn't exactly comparing apples to oranges, but it *is* like comparing peaches to nectarines. Humans and mice are not exactly the same except for size. As an example of metabolic differences between animals, adults can ingest 50 g of xylitol without problems (maybe diarrhea). Fifty percent of dogs weighing 50 pounds will die given 2 grams.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Does this kind of scaling effect of toxicity with body weight exist for two organisms of the same specie, between a newborn and a 5 times heavier adult, or perhaps two healthy adults with same BMI who naturally have different weights?

Comment: This isn't a "scaling event of toxicity". It's a physiological difference in metabolism. The comments are quite clear.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am not sure if I understand you. This is not my field, so maybe I am missing something. I asked you a different question altogether in my last comment. Intuitively, it feels to me that an x amount of toxin will do more harm to an healthy average child than a healthy average adult (larger in size). Can this assumption be scientifically justified? Both are same species. Can we use something like (body weight)^0.67 scaling factor to judge the effect of the toxin, as suggested in the comment by user338907 ?

Comment: @TLR78agonist - Intuition isn't science. Scientists don't give human beings of differing weights toxins to test their ability to metabolize/survive. Also, not all toxins are created equally. If toxins must be administered (e.g. some chemotherapeutic agents are quite toxic), they are given in the lowest dosage shown to be effective. That's based on trials, not intuition.

Comment: @anongoodnurse My point was, whether such a scaling effect exists within the same specie, human or non-human. Scientists test effect of stuff on animals all the time, so I thought someone may have tested this. Agreed that intuition is not science, but is often the guiding principle in science. Surely a scientific method will determine whether this thing that appears intuitive to me is actually true or not. I just wanted to know if it is scientifically known to be true.